# Hyper-v: Cannot convert value \n"Link to VHD file" to type "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ControllerType"

Tags: hyper-v, winrm, vhd

I am trying to deploy a vhd on hyper-v. Can I pass the link of VHD file stored somewhere while running following command:

```
r= s.run_ps("Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName MY_VM3 https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/alpine.vhd ")
```

S3 bucket is public. I am using pywinrm module of python 3.

I am getting following error:
Add-VMHardDiskDrive : Cannot bind parameter \'ControllerType\'. Cannot convert value \n"Link to VHD file" to type "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ControllerType"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach a VHD to a VM across internet. The virtual disk must be saved on a local volume, on a cluster-shared volume or on an SMB share for a virtual machine to access.